# My music play command isn't working or sending any error, how can I fix this?

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to make a my bot play music, and so when I run my command, it doesn't show any error or joining the vc. however when I'm not in the vc it does send me a message telling me to execute this command after joining the vc. I do have Ytdl and YtSearch installed ofcourse, but I can't figure out how to fix this. I'm using repl btw. I'm using Aliases for the skip and stop command.

The code is below.

```js
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const ytSearch = require('yt-search');
    
const queue = new Map();
    
module.exports = {
    name: 'play',
    aliases: ['skip', 'stop'], 
    description: 'Plays music',
    async execute(message, args, cmd, client, Discord){
    
    
        const voice_channel = message.member.voice.channel;
        if (!voice_channel) return message.channel.send('You need to be in a channel to execute this command!');
        const permissions = voice_channel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
        if (!permissions.has('CONNECT')) return message.channel.send('You dont have the correct permissins');
        if (!permissions.has('SPEAK')) return message.channel.send('You dont have the correct permissins');
    
    
        const server_queue = queue.get(message.guild.id);
    
    
        if (cmd === 'play'){
            if (!args.length) return message.channel.send('You need to send the second argument!');
            let song = {};
    
                
            if (ytdl.validateURL(args[0])) {
                const song_info = await ytdl.getInfo(args[0]);
                song = { title: song_info.videoDetails.title, url: song_info.videoDetails.video_url }
            } else {
                    
                    
                const video_finder = async (query) =>{
                    const video_result = await ytSearch(query);
                    return (video_result.videos.length > 1) ? video_result.videos[0] : null;
                }
    
                const video = await video_finder(args.join(' '));
                if (video){
                    song = { title: video.title, url: video.url }
                } else {
                     message.channel.send('Error finding video.');
                }
            }
    
            if (!server_queue){
    
                const queue_constructor = {
                    voice_channel: voice_channel,
                    text_channel: message.channel,
                    connection: null,
                    songs: []
                }  
                    
                queue.set(message.guild.id, queue_constructor);
                queue_constructor.songs.push(song);
        
                try {
                    const connection = await voice_channel.join();
                    queue_constructor.connection = connection;
                    video_player(message.guild, queue_constructor.songs[0]);
                } catch (err) {
                    queue.delete(message.guild.id);
                    message.channel.send('There was an error connecting!');
                     throw err;
                }
            } else{
                server_queue.songs.push(song);
                return message.channel.send(` **${song.title}** added to queue!`);
            }
        }
    
        else if(cmd === 'skip') skip_song(message, server_queue);
        else if(cmd === 'stop') stop_song(message, server_queue);
    }
       
}
    
const video_player = async (guild, song) => {
    const song_queue = queue.get(guild.id);
    
    if (!song) {
        song_queue.voice_channel.leave();
        queue.delete(guild.id);
        return;
    }
    const stream = ytdl(song.url, { filter: 'audioonly' });
    song_queue.connection.play(stream, { seek: 0, volume: 0.5 })
    .on('finish', () => {
        song_queue.songs.shift();
        video_player(guild, song_queue.songs[0]);
    });
    await song_queue.text_channel.send(` Now playing **${song.title}**`)
}
    
const skip_song = (message, server_queue) => {
    if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.channel.send('You need to be in a channel to execute this command!');
    if(!server_queue){
        return message.channel.send(`There are no songs in queue `);
    }
    server_queue.connection.dispatcher.end();
}
    
const stop_song = (message, server_queue) => {
    if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.channel.send('You need to be in a channel to execute this command!');
    server_queue.songs = [];
    server_queue.connection.dispatcher.end();
}
```

Comment: So when you're in a voice channel, the bot successfully joins the same channel and plays the song. But when you are not in any voice channel it says you need to be in a voice channel, right?